# Deploy Java War in docker

Tags: java, docker

I want to deploy my war file on my docker

DOCKERFILE

```
FROM java:8
EXPOSE 8080
ADD /name.war name.war
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","atp.war"]
```

I build the image

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t name .
```

But when i try to run it

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -t name
```

> no main manifest attribute, in name.war

what is this and how do I solve it?

Comment: I never deployed anything before. Usually I just click start with tomcat on intellij and it just works. What else do I need ? **What is the main class of a web project??**

Comment: What is inside the war ? Does it run outside docker container ? Do you need to deploy it to tomcat or any other server ?

Comment: Inside the war is a java web application. I need tomcat to deploy on intellij..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a war which you want to deploy in tomcat, you should start from a tomcat docker base image.  Something like:

```
FROM tomcat:9-jre8-alpine
ADD /name.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
```

See the docs for the tomcat base image https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/

Comment: No - the tomcat image has everything in it already. All you need to do is put your war in and it should do the rest.